# MS SQL Server IO read increase appear randomly

Tags: sql-server, database, io

The number of read (IOPS) in my MS SQL Server database increased randomly even during the night (low activities) from 0.3 MB/SEC (normal) to 25-30 MB/SEC.

After like 30 minutes, it's capped to 6 MB/SEC by Amazon cloud service (I have a SATA 200 GB volume). If I wait 6 hours and do nothing, it's still capped to 6 MB/SEC. But if I change my recovery model (simple mode) to full and I re-switch it to simple everything restart to be normal (0.3 MB/SEC) instantly.

During the increase, the resource Waits Buffer I/O and Logging are very high and all my reads wait are in my database `.MDF` data file. I have seen that the IO_completion wait type has increased too.

The value of my IoStallReadMS is 28485797489.

I have no idea of which operation can cause that and how to stop it.

I have not activated the auto-shrink and my backup maintenance schedule seem to have no link with that.